# Get offset relative to an ancestor in jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a little scrollable div which contains a very large tree of results, nested hierarchically and displayed as a huge indented list. I would like that div to scroll down to one of the tree items when an autocompleted suggestion elsewhere on the page is clicked. The issue is calculating the offset to scroll to within the scrollable div. I need to get the distance between the top of the target and the top of the scrollable div, but there are several complications.

I have code that looks like this:

```
$('#coltree').animate({
    scrollTop: $node.offset().top - $('#coltree').offset().top
}, 800);
```

Where `coltree` is the id of the containing, scrollable div and $node is a jQuery object containing the element I'm trying to scroll to (inside the `coltree` div).

And now, the complications. I need to get the distance between the top of the scrollable div and the top of the target element. The method I used above only works if `coltree` is already scrolled all the way up. If, for instance, you have already scrolled to one element, clicking on another suggestion will scroll to the wrong place, since the contents of `coltree` have moved relative to the page.

I don't want to take the tree out of the scrollable div as there is content before and after it and the tree is potentially many pages long. Using jQuery's `.position()` method won't work as `coltree` is not the direct parent of the target. I need a way to get or calculate the vertical position of an element relative to some arbitrary ancestor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I figured out was to wrap `coltree` in another div, and making that wrapper the scrolling div. Since `coltree` now moves with the target div, subtracting their offsets as above gives the correct value every time. The only required change to the above code is to animate the scrollable wrapper rather than `coltree`.